# Why can we have unused functions but we can't have unused variables?

Tags: performance, go, compilation

Unused variables will block compiling (that's a good thing) but compiler don't really care about unused functions, is there an explanation ?

Comment: You are not using them does not mean another consumer of your class will not. Unused variables don't by default block compiling. It's a warning as far as I know.

Comment: @OguzOzgul You're right but, in a main package ?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the originally marked one ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549228/why-does-golang-allow-compilation-of-unused-function-parameters), as it's about unused function _parameters_ and not the _functions_ themselves), but this is a possible duplicate of [Why Does Golang Allow Compilation of Unused Functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564935/why-does-golang-allow-compilation-of-unused-functions).

Comment: @OguzOzgul Unused variables is a compile-time _error_, not a warning. There are no compiler warnings in Go. And if a package has an unexported function which if the package itself doesn't call, noone else will as noone else can reach that (not even with reflection).

Comment: Please forgive my dumbness for commenting on this question as if it was tagged c#. I don't know what is wrong with me :)

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes – although short, it's a completely valid question. Very healthy curiosity.

Comment: @tomasz thanks for the comment (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour seems consistent between variables and functions – both are allowed in a package-level scope, even if unused.

This snippet is compiling without any issues:

```
package main

var v int // unused variable

func f() {} // unused function

func main() {}
```

Now, when it comes to local scope things are different and unused variables generate errors. Same for function literals (named nested functions are not allowed in Go):

```
func main() {
    func() {}
}
// Error: func literal evaluated but not used
```

Finally, why is only local scope checked for unused variables? Because usually it's a bug (for examples, in Go, due to an accidental usage of `:=`). And compiler saved me many times here. Consider this:

```
func f() (err error) {
    if somthing {
        err := g() // err is unused variable! I really meant `=`.
    }
    return
}
```

For global (package-level) scopes unused variables and functions are usually just polluting the namespace as, for example, someone forgot to remove them after refactoring. There're some tools which helps detecting these, for example:

1. https://github.com/opennota/check
2. https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter (uses the previous package)
3. https://github.com/remyoudompheng/go-misc/blob/master/deadcode/deadcode.go

I also found a [post by Russ Cox](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Mo9gZDkg9vw/F23ZRPKVF_MJ) commenting on the issue:

> I have been writing some C code with gcc -Wall -Werror recently. It
>   makes prototyping code somewhat difficult to be told "you didn't use
>   that function, go fix it" when you're just trying to test what you've
>   got so far, or commenting out calls that are possibly causing trouble.
>   Of course the same is true for warning about unused local variables
>   too. The difference is that, in Go, because of :=, an unused local
>   variable is very often a bug, while an unused unexported function is
>   much less often a bug.
>
> Russ