# Meaning of underscore in a Go function parameter

Tags: go

Came accross the below function [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter). I noticed the last parameter is identified with `_`. What is the intent of this pattern?

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
}
```

Comment: Related questions: 1. [Getting method parameter names in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377433/getting-method-parameter-names-in-golang); 2. [Why does Go allow compilation of unused function parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549228/why-does-go-allow-compilation-of-unused-function-parameters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means "ignore that parameter", the reason that they still need the last parameter here is because they want to pass it as `type Handle` to the function `GET`, which has the signature:

`type Handle func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, Params)`

If you simply pass something like `func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` it will not be treated as `type Handle`.

Answer (score 9):

_ is the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier).  It's in the signature to show that the value doesn't get used, so the signature will still match the methods of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Using "_" in place of a parameter name fulfills the obligations of a higher-level "function as a parameter" without getting a warning about an unused parameter. In your case, I believe the compiler is told to ignore all incoming "POST" data, thus in effect reducing the request to the functionality of a "GET".

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, it is a [blank identifier](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank). For instance, consider the following example:

```
func main() {
     nums := []int{5, 3, 4}
     max := nums[0]
     for _, num := range nums {
         if num > max {
            max = num
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("max:", max)
}
```

If you aren't going to use an index value, you can just ignore storing it by using `_` instead of a variable name.=.

Comment: The OP's question is about function parameter. I don't think you are answering the question.