# C# alternative to Go placeholder variables

Tags: c#, go

In Go, I can easily write something like this:

```
func isAvailableForUser(_ context.Context) bool {
    return true;
}
```

But C# behaviour is different:

```
private bool IsAvailableForUser(IContext _) => true;
```

`_` is the variable name instead of a void-like placeholder. What is the alternative to the Go code in C#?

Comment: What version of Go and what version of C# are you using?

Comment: _"But C# behaviour is different:"_ - what do you mean by that? In Go, [any function parameter named `_` is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079820/meaning-of-underscore-in-a-go-function-parameter) but callers still need to provide an argument for it - it's the same in C#: a method parameter named `_` still needs arguments, it just signifies to the consumer of that called function/method that the argument _will_ be ignored (and it also disables compiler warnings about unused parameters).

Comment: Nitpicking: 1) It's called ["blank identifier"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) in Go; 2) The language [is called Go](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang). As to the essense of the question: you cannot, but that's not a big deal IMO.

Comment: The `_` char in c# is a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) - from documentation: *"Discards are placeholder variables that are intentionally unused in application code. "*. I don't read "Go", but from your question text it seems like the two methods are equivalent.

Comment: @Dai C# 7.0 and Go 1.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Go doesn't support overloading](https://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading) and [parameter default value](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/-5MCaivW0qQ?pli=1), so in order to hold the consistency of function signature, it has to retain some parameters.

But C# supports, so if the method doesn't require the parameter, you can implement a parameterless method. Later, if you need to pass this method to a delegate such as `Func<IContext, bool>`, you can define an overloaded method to call this parameterless method.

```
private bool IsAvailableForUser() => true;
private bool IsAvailableForUser(IContext _) => IsAvailableForUser();
....
Func<IContext, bool> d = IsAvailableForUser;
```

If the parameter name consists of [underscores followed by a number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0060), the C# analyzer will not complain that the parameter is unused. So basically, the two functions in your question are equivalent, except for that you can use the parameter in C#.

Comment: Interesting link `things are simpler without it` for whom?

Comment: _"But C# supports, so if the method doesn't require the parameter, you can implement a parameterless method"_ - another alternative is to use an explicitly optional parameter, e.g. `bool IsAvailableForUser(IContext? _ = null)`. BTW, if `IContext` can be implemented by a `struct` type then consider adding a generic method so that the method won't cause unnecessary boxing, e.g. `IsAvailableForUser<TContext>(TContext _ = default) where TContext : IContext`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, for the language developers I think.

Comment: @shingo in that case, for example, using two parameters named `_` in C# throws an error. The interface that I'm implementing has this method signature: `bool IsAvailableForUser(IContext context)`. Does that mean that I must implement the same method with the same parameter names only? And do I really need to optimise a method that has no logic?..

Comment: @GettingPleasure The parameter name doesn't need to be same as the interface, it depends on your practice. Multiple parameter names cannot be the same, you can name them as `_1`, `_2`, etc if you don't like to see warnings.

Comment: @GettingPleasure IIRC, C# 8.0 and later do allow for multiple discard parameters named `_` (though possibly only in an explicit interface implementation - or when defining a lambda for delegate parameter - I need to double-check that), whereas C# 7.x only allows at-most one parameter named `_`. I might be wrong, though.