# Go: Returning always nil error to implement interface

Tags: go, error-handling

I have an `interface`:

```golang
type encoder interface {
    encode() ([]byte, error)
}
```

Some implementations of `encoder` return an `error`:

```golang
type fooEncoder string

func (e fooEncoder) encode() ([]byte, error) {
    if isSomeValidityCheck(e) {
        return []byte(e), nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Invalid type!")
}
```

But for others, there will never be an error:

```golang
type boolEncoder bool

func (e boolEncoder) encode() ([]byte, error) {
    if e {
        return []byte{0xff}, nil
    }
    return []byte{0x00}, nil
}
```

Is it idiomatic/correct to say a method will return an error, even if it will always be `nil`, so that it conforms to an `interface`? I have `boolEncoder.encode` returning an `error` only so that it conforms to `encoder` and can be used as such.

Comment: are you looking forward to implement the binary marshaller interface ?  maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely OK / normal. Often it's more important to implement an interface than to reduce the code (of the method).

There are numerous examples in the standard lib too.

For example [`bytes/Buffer.Write()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.Write) implements [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) with

```
func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

But writing to an in-memory buffer cannot fail, it documents that it never will return a non-`nil` error:

> Write appends the contents of p to the buffer, growing the buffer as needed. The return value n is the length of p; **err is always nil**. If the buffer becomes too large, Write will panic with ErrTooLarge.

`Buffer.Write()` could have a signature that doesn't return anything because its return values carry no information (`n` is always `len(p)` and `err` is always `nil`), but then you couldn't use `bytes.Buffer` as an `io.Writer`, which is way more important.

See related: [Is unnamed arguments a thing in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950877/is-unnamed-arguments-a-thing-in-go/40951013#40951013;) and [Why does Go allow compilation of unused function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549228/why-does-go-allow-compilation-of-unused-function-parameters/33759531#33759531)