# Potentially unused parameter in go when using testify's suite package

Tags: go, testing, testify

I want to execute subtests using the `testify/suite` [package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite).

I am declaring my Unit suite as follows

```golang
type UnitSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
}

func TestUnitSuite(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, &UnitSuite{})
}
```

and here is my subtest

```golang
func (us *UnitSuite) ΤestSomething() {
    for i := range testVars {
        i := i
        us.T().Run(testVars[i].name, func(t *testing.T) {
        ...
```

Ι am getting the following linting warning for `func(t *testing.T)`

```
potentially unused parameter: 't'unusedparams
```

When trying to substitute with the testing suite's function `T()` that is supposes to retrieve the `testing` context

```golang
us.T().Run(testVars[i].name, func(us.T()) {
```

I get this error in `func(us.T())` <-- errors out

```
missing ',' in parameter listsyntax
```

What is the way to go about this that does not produce neither errors nor linting warnings?

Comment: `func(_ *testing.T) {`

Comment: Thanks for this if you post it as the answer I will mark it as the solution

Comment: closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549228/why-does-go-allow-compilation-of-unused-function-parameters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to declare an unused parameter (usually to satisfy an interface or other requirements), you can name it a single underscore. For example:

```
Run(name, func(_ *testing.T) {})
```

Note that you cannot put a *value* in function declaration, so `func(us.T()) {` is always wrong.